# How do I _properly_ serve an XAP file from a self-hosted WCF service?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, streaming, xap, self-hosting

I have myself a self-hosted WCF server setup, which serves a clientaccesspolicy.xml and an index.htm which is just points to my xap (accessible via app.xap).

I'm currently serving them via the following code:

```
Public Function GetPolicy() As System.IO.Stream Implements IClientAccessPolicy.GetPolicy

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml"
    Return New IO.MemoryStream(IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Server Files/ClientAccessPolicy.xml"))

End Function

Public Function GetIndex() As IO.Stream Implements ISilverlightServer.GetIndex

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html"
    Return New IO.MemoryStream(IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Server Files/index.htm"))

End Function

Public Function GetXap() As IO.Stream Implements ISilverlightServer.GetXap

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/x-silverlight-app"
    Return New IO.MemoryStream(IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Server Files/app.xap"))

End Function
```

It works, does the job I'm after. However, I don't think this streams the xap properly, and I know it's a streaming type. If this isn't streaming it properly, how should I stream it?

(The endpoint that the XAP and index.htm files are coming through has a webHttpBinding binding)

Is it being streamed properly? Or should I make some changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is fine, the XAP file doesn't need to be *streamed* to the client. Actually, it needs to be first *fully* downloaded (thus buffered at the client) for the SL application to start, so you don't need to worry about streaming in this case.

Comment: Thanks, so what's the 'loading screen' stuff innate of? Just the download progress?

Comment: The "circling dots" which show up while the SL page is being loaded? Yes, I think this is a download progress indicator.