# Deploy a silverlight application with wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, deployment, xap

I try to deploy a silverlight application that consumes a wcf service.
I know that I can simply deploy the silverlight application by putting the .xap file to the apache web server and referencing upon it in a html.

Now what is unclear to me, do I have to deploy the webservice (the .svc file in the .Web folder of the silverligh project) seperately or is that included in the .xap file?

Thanks

Comment: of cource web-service should be separated.

p.s. Why are you using Apache insted of IIS?

Comment: because Apache is free and IIS not. So the .svc file has to be deployed on a IIS web server?

Comment: Even IIS is also free, i would prefer IIS instead of Apache for deploying dot net applications.

Comment: But is it necessary to use IIS or is it possible to deploy the webservice on an apache? I mean does the wcf web service need an ASP.NET environment or can it just be copied on an apache server? How do I have to deploy the webservice on an IIS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I \_properly\_ serve an XAP file from a self-hosted WCF service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322254/how-do-i-properly-serve-an-xap-file-from-a-self-hosted-wcf-service)